# Efficient way to apply a grouping vector in R

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have some grouping information in the form of a grouping vector:

```
group = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
```

So this is saying I have three groups: two groups of size 2 and one group of size 3. Now suppose I have a vector (I've added random numbers)

```
x = c(1.5, 3.1, 5.4, -4.5, 2.2, 4.4, 1.1)
```

Is there an efficient way in R to loop over this vector and applying certain functions within the group?

For example, summation within each group, using a for loop would be:

```
sums = rep(0,3)
for (i in 1:3){
grp_ids = which(group == i)
sums[i] = sum(x[grp_ids])
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `tapply(x, group, sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` from {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)

group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
x = c(1.5, 3.1, 5.4, -4.5, 2.2, 4.4, 1.1)

df <- data.frame(group, x)

result <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(sums = sum(x))

> print(result)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  group  sums
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   4.6
2     2   0.9
3     3   7.7
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance, take a look at the `collapse` package.

```
library(collapse)

# efficient group summing
fsum(x, group)
#>   1   2   3 
#> 4.6 0.9 7.7
# apply a generic function
BY(x, group, min)
#>    1    2    3 
#>  1.5 -4.5  1.1
# apply a list of functions
collap(x, group, list(sum, prod, min, max))
#>   group sum.X  prod.X min.X max.X
#> 1     1   4.6   4.650   1.5   3.1
#> 2     2   0.9 -24.300  -4.5   5.4
#> 3     3   7.7  10.648   1.1   4.4
```